# Hugo website on GitHub not showing themes

Tags: github, themes, hugo

My Hugo website is configured to publish in a folder called `docs`, which is the source (`master/docs`) for the website on my GitHub repo; however, the website itself won't show any css/js.

I've tried manually changing the reference for css in the `index.html` file so that the path is `khobbs3.github.io/docs/main.....css` but that doesn't seem to help either.

The repo: https://github.com/KHobbs3/ktechnology

The website:
https://github.com/KHobbs3/ktechnology

---

**RESOLVED**: set up new repos following https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/ tutorial.

**Published site**: http://khobbs3.github.io

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are no CSS /js files on the static folder. Hugo uses the static folder to render the js and CSS files and also for images.

Comment: I've tried manually cping the automatically generated css/js files into the static folder and it still does not put them into use on the webpage

Comment: did u build after copying the generated CSS/js file? Your repo seems to be unavailable